# why does datetime not change in this dbfiddle?

Tags: sql-server

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2017e16407a2aae0318b47d1b70d5af)

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(id_log int, dt datetime);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    (1,getdate());
INSERT INTO mytable select id_log+1,dateadd(HH,2,getdate()) from mytable;

INSERT INTO mytable select id_log+(select max(id_log) from mytable),dateadd(HH,id_log+10,dt) from mytable;

INSERT INTO mytable select id_log+(select max(id_log) from mytable),dateadd(HH,id_log+10,dt) from mytable;

select 
  *
from mytable;
```

output:

```
id_log  dt
1       2020-01-06 18:56:29
2       2020-01-06 18:56:29
3       2020-01-06 18:56:29
4       2020-01-06 18:56:29
5       2020-01-06 18:56:29
6       2020-01-06 18:56:29
7       2020-01-06 18:56:29
8       2020-01-06 18:56:29
```

Expectation was that the datetime increased by several hours...

Comment: Looks like a problem with dbfiddle, it works when I try it on a regular Azure SQL Database. For what it's worth, changing the column from datetime to datetime2(3) produces the expected output.

Comment: Appears to be a bug with dbfiddle.  I ran this on a SQL Server 2017 system and the dates are different as expected.

Comment: Really a bug. I check all versions available - only 2012 gives correct result. After change `dt` datatype to `datetime2` all versions shows correct results.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining why I go lost … , I should have thought about  datetime2, and/or testing locally...